# 5'UTR and 3'UTR annotation in yeast

Tags: sequence-annotation, bed, gtf

I am working on a project in which I need to compute several parameters (such GC content and length) of 5'UTR and 3'UTR sequences of *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* yeast genes.

The problem is finding a proper annotation for these regions in yeast. I have tried with BiomaRt and these sequences are not available for yeast. I have also tried with UCSC table browser to obtain a BED file with 5'UTR or 3'UTR sequences but it is returning only coordinates of tRNAs, pseudogenes, ncRNAs.

In summary, **is there a straight-forward way to obtain an annotation for 5'UTR and 3'UTR regions in *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* yeast**?

Comment: Sorry, is for Saccharomyces cerevisiae. I am going to edit the question just in case.

Comment: isn't there an equivalent of AceView for Yeast ? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/Research/Acembly/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am unaware of any "official" or gold-standard UTR annotations in *S. cerevisiae*.

One option is to [use the annotations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE39128) from the TIF-Seq publication ([**Pelechano et al. 2013**](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v497/n7447/full/nature12121.html)).

The `GSE39128_tsedall.txt.gz` file contains the major isoforms identified. It would be up to you to computational associate each transcript with a given gene. It is also up to you to determine which major isoforms are present in your dataset. Furthermore based on my own experience there is often a significant number of discrepancies between what I see in an NGS dataset (e.g. RNA-Seq) and what is called as a possible isoform in these annotations. However, a lot of this could be related to the inherent technological limitations of the method.

If you look at the SGD genome browser they provide some additional UTR annotations. Derived from [**Nagalakshmi et al. 2008**](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/320/5881/1344).

You can find the relevant annotations for those UTR's in their supplemental data section. The file is `1158441_tables_s2_to_s6.zip` and inside you will find *TableS4* which seems to contain what you seek.

There might be more resources but these are the two main ones I'm aware of.

Answer (score 7):

I found the following two files in https://downloads.yeastgenome.org/sequence/S288C_reference/:

- [SGD_all_ORFs_3prime_UTRs.fsa](https://downloads.yeastgenome.org/sequence/S288C_reference/SGD_all_ORFs_3prime_UTRs.fsa)
- [SGD_all_ORFs_5prime_UTRs.fsa](https://downloads.yeastgenome.org/sequence/S288C_reference/SGD_all_ORFs_5prime_UTRs.fsa)

According to the README files in the same directory, these are (the README for the 5' file is equivalent):

> SGD_all_ORFs_3prime_UTRs.README
>
> Information about the SGD_all_ORFs_3prime_UTRs.fsa file.
>
> This file contains sequences for predicted 3' UTR sequences for all
>   characterized, uncharacterized and dubious ORFs in S288c.
>
> 3' UTR coordinates were retrieved from YeastMine
>   (yeastmine.yeastgenome.org) on July 3, 2017 using the stop coordinates
>   of both the predicted transcript and gene sequences. A BED file with
>   these coordinates was made. BED files were fixed on Sept 22, 2017 to
>   account for strandedness. Sequences were batch downloaded again in
>   FASTA format from USCS Genome Table Browser on Sept 22, 2017
>   (https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=604915183_aUc9FZ1vwyAccGti1uI0wteYEM7x)
>
> File created: 2017-08-25

Those therefore seem to be the 3' and 5' UTR sequences of all yeast genes in FASTA format and should be exactly what you need.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Pengyao yes, apparently yeastdownloads.org are using a bad SSL certificate. I guess they'll fix it eventually.